# How to use SSSE3 with OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

In freak_demo.cpp, there's this comment:

```
// MATCHER
// The standard Hamming distance can be used such as
// BruteForceMatcher<Hamming> matcher;
// or the proposed cascade of hamming distance using SSSE3
```

But how to use SSSE3? It's best if this comment also includes the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember you should be able to set SSE support when generating OpenCV project using CMake and then compiling OpenCV. It is possible that some binary versions of OpenCV which are distributed could have been already compiled with this setting.

This could be also helpful- [OpenCV Install Guide](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide).

Comment: Thanks. After that, does the line "BruteForceMatcher<Hamming> matcher" need to be change?

Comment: Sorry, but unfortunately I do not know this code. Probably enabling SSE3 would be enough. Maybe this could be helpful for you also: http://dovgalecs.com/blog/freak-descriptor-in-matlab/. Looks like it is very close to your problem- maybe this post's author could help you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (I didn't write the FREAK code myself but had to work with the fREAK guys a lot) the BruteForceMatcher class from OpenCV was either changed or removed in the latest version. Anyway, this part of the code is broken if you use the latest stable release (2.4.3) and there are some bug requests to update it, but I have no idea wether it's in the pipeline.